# Web page in Azure Mobile app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I have created a Mobile App in New Azure portal. It has many APIs available for mobile users and some API for admin. we are creating Admin page (HTML with jquery). Is it possible to host the Admin page in Mobile App or do i need to create separate web app in Azure portal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mobile app is essentially a web app customized for mobile features.  So, yes, this is possible.

Place your HTML page (ie: index.html) in wwwroot of the web app.